# Why is my rate limiter enforcing a different rate than specified?

Tags: c++

**The Problem:** I'm writing a game (as a programming exercise) from scratch. I'm trying to limit the number of game logic loops ("ticks") per second. I've set it to an arbitrary 100 ticks/second. But no matter what I do, it seems to run at ~130 ticks/second. Could it possibly be rounding errors adding up? Something else? Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

*Note: my codebase is much larger than this, but for the purposes of this question, I've stripped it down as much as possible without breaking the rate limiter.*

---

**The Output:**

```
counter 1 sleep_for(5ms)
counter 2 sleep_for(2ms)
[snip]
counter 132 sleep_for(3ms)
counter 133 sleep_for(3ms)
133 TPS last 1003ms
counter 134 sleep_for(3ms)
counter 135 sleep_for(3ms)
[snip]
counter 265 sleep_for(3ms)
counter 266 sleep_for(3ms)
133 TPS last 1004ms
counter 267 sleep_for(3ms)
counter 268 sleep_for(3ms)
[snip]
counter 399 sleep_for(3ms)
counter 400 sleep_for(3ms)
134 TPS last 1006ms
```

---

**The Code:**

(The two main functions to look at are ThreadRateLimiter::Tock() and TickRateCounter::Tock())

```
#include <chrono>
#include <exception>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

const int TICK_RATE = 100;
const chrono::milliseconds TIME_PER_TICK =
        chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(chrono::seconds(1)) / TICK_RATE;

template <class T>
class TickTocker
{
public:
    virtual void Tick() = 0;
    virtual T Tock() = 0;
    virtual T TickTock()
    {
        Tick();
        return Tock();
    }
};
```

Ticker:

```
class Ticker : public TickTocker<long>
{
public:
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const Ticker& counter);
    Ticker() :
        Ticker(0)
    {}
    Ticker(long counter) :
        mTicks(counter),
        mTicksLast(mTicks)
    {}
    Ticker(const Ticker& counter) :
        Ticker(counter.mTicks)
    {}
    bool operator==(const long i)
    {
        return mTicks == i;
    }
    void Tick() override
    {
        mTicks++;
    }
    long Tock() override
    {
        long diff = mTicks - mTicksLast;
        mTicksLast = mTicks;
        return diff;
    }
// private:
    long mTicks;
    long mTicksLast;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const Ticker& counter)
{
    return (stream << "counter " << counter.mTicks);
}
```

TickTracker:

```
class TickTracker : public TickTocker<chrono::milliseconds>
{
public:
    TickTracker() :
        mTime(chrono::steady_clock::now()),
        mLastTime(mTime)
    {}
    void Tick() override
    {
        mTime = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    }
    chrono::milliseconds Tock() override
    {
        chrono::milliseconds diff = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(mTime - mLastTime);
        mLastTime = mTime;
        return diff;
    }
protected:
    chrono::time_point<chrono::steady_clock> mTime;
    chrono::time_point<chrono::steady_clock> mLastTime;
};
```

ThreadRateLimiter:

```
class ThreadRateLimiter : public TickTracker
{
public:
    ThreadRateLimiter() : TickTracker(),
        mMsFast(chrono::milliseconds(0))
    {}
    void Tick() override
    {
        mCounter.Tick();
        TickTracker::Tick();
        if (mCounter == 1)
        {
            TickTracker::Tock();
        }
    }
    chrono::milliseconds Tock()
    {
        chrono::milliseconds diff = TickTracker::Tock();
        chrono::milliseconds remaining = TIME_PER_TICK - diff;
        /*
        * If we always sleep the full remaining time, we'll alternate between sleeping for "minimum" and "maximum" sleep
        * times. Sleeping the full remaining time only when we exceed the average makes for more stable sleep times.
        */
        bool fullSleep = (mMsFast.count() > (TIME_PER_TICK.count() / 2));
        mMsFast += remaining;
        if (mMsFast.count() > 0)
        {
            chrono::milliseconds sleep = fullSleep ? mMsFast : (chrono::milliseconds(mMsFast.count() / 2));
            cout << mCounter << " sleep_for(" << sleep.count() << "ms)" << endl;
            this_thread::sleep_for(mMsFast);
            mMsFast -= sleep;
        }
        mCounter.Tock();
        return remaining;
    }
private:
    Ticker mCounter;
    chrono::milliseconds mMsFast;
};
```

TickRateCounter:

```
class TickRateCounter : public TickTracker
{
public:
    TickRateCounter(string rateLabel) : TickTracker(),
        mRateLabel(rateLabel)
    {}
    void Tick() override
    {
        mCounter.Tick();
        TickTracker::Tick();
    }
    chrono::milliseconds Tock() override
    {
        if (chrono::duration_cast<chrono::seconds>(mTime - mLastTime).count() >= 1)
        {
            chrono::milliseconds duration = TickTracker::Tock();
            cout << (mCounter.Tock() / chrono::duration_cast<chrono::seconds>(duration).count()) << " " << mRateLabel
                << " last " << duration.count() << "ms" << endl;
            return duration;
        }
        return chrono::milliseconds(0);
    }
// private:
    Ticker mCounter;
    string mRateLabel;
};
```

Main:

```
int main()
{
    ThreadRateLimiter mRateLimiter;
    TickRateCounter mTpsCounter("TPS"); // TPS = Ticks per second. Tick = one game loop

    while (mTpsCounter.mCounter.mTicks < 400)
    {
        mRateLimiter.TickTock();
        mTpsCounter.TickTock();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `sleep_for` sleeps for *at least* the specified time. There is no upper limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to have rate limiting is:

```
//pseudocode follows
const frame_duration = something;
last = now();
while(true)
{
    process_your_frame_here()

    do
    {
        t = now();
        sleep(0); // or whatever fits your system
    }
    while(t < last + frame_duration);

    last = last + frame_duration; // THIS IS KEY
    // last = now; // would not produce the right framerate 
}
```

Basically, you delay your frame, as you seem to do. But when bookkeeping the time spent, you only add the time you wanted (frame_duration). So, over multiple frame, it evens out.

To elaborate, if `now()` starts at 1000 (whatever unit) and you set `frame_duration` to 200, frame 1 will only run after 1200, frame 2 after 1400, ... frame 100 after 20100, giving exact frame rates over long periods of time.

Comment: Ugh. Thank you! I'm definitely going to do a sleep(frame_duration - (now() - last)) instead of that busy while. But as usual, I was overcomplicating things for no reason.